# Hive - LIKE operator with special characters

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am new to hive and trying to pull all the records in a table which match a particular format.

```
> Table structure-
>     (
>     id string,
>     col_json string
>     )
```

Within the json col_json, there is an attribute which is a text within which I am looking for the format

> - \"abc\":\"xyz\"

.

I am using a where condition like below - 
    and     get_json_object(a.col_json,'$.Attributes[*].attributeValues[*].attributeValue') like '%\"abc\":\"xyz\"%'

But this does not seem to be working as I am not getting any rows returned.
Can someone suggest what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Add one more backslash** before each backslash in like function and run again

> hive>
>   get_json_object(a.col_json,'$.Attributes[].attributeValues[].attributeValue')
>   like '%\\"abc\\":\\"xyz\\"%'

With **one back slash hive** considers it is been used as **escape character()** so we need to use **two back slashes(\)** then hive considers as ****